# interactive report not responding to dynamic action "refresh region"

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

it usually works fine all i need to do is create a dynamic action and specify

```
when
event              dialog closed
selection type     Region
Region             MyRegion
```

```
Identification
Action             Refresh

Affected Elements  
Selection Type     Region
Region             MyRegion
```

but somehow the report is not closing when dialog is closed.
do i have to bind the report with the dialog ?

Answer (score 0):

Below works for me :-
Create Dynamic Action
Action : Execute PL/SQL Code
PL/SQL Code : null;
Items to Submit :

Identification
Action             Refresh
Affected Elements
Selection Type     Region
Region             MyRegion